# Adding object to nsmutablearray doesn't work and any added objects disappear from my tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, nsmutablearray

Through delegation I created a view controller that takes the input from textfields and passes it back and adds it to an nsmutablearray, successfully adding a row for it. whenever i navigate away from the tableview my newly appended object just disappears. Here is some code to give you a better idea of what i might be doing wrong.

TableViewController.h -

```
@interface TableViewController : UITableViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> 

@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *codeList; 
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSMutableArray *codeArray;

@end
```

TableViewController.m -

```
@interface TableViewController ()
@end

@implementation MCTableViewController

@synthesize codeList;
@synthesize codeArray;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;

    self.codeList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Array",
                                               @"Pointer",
                                               @"Class",
                                               @"Protocol",
                                               @"Delegate",
                                               nil];


    self.codeDescArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:
                                                  @"Array Description",
                                                  @"Pointer Description",
                                                  @"Class Description",
                                                  @"Protocol Description",
                                                  @"Delegate Description",
                                                  nil];
)
```

In the same class I programmatically created a button that moves to the view where data is supposed to be passed back. code below. This is done through delegation.

```
- (void)addNewCodeButtonPressed {
    AddNewCodeVC *addVC = [[AddNewCodeVC alloc] init];
    addVC.dataDelegate = self;
    UINavigationController *navBar = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:addVC];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:navBar animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Here is where the delegate logic is created in AddNewCodeVC.h -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "TableViewController.h"

@class AddNewCodeVC;
@protocol addNewCellData <NSObject>
- (void)sendDataToTableView:(NSString*)code codeDesc: (NSString*)desc;
@end

@interface AddNewCodeVC :  UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate> {
    __weak id dataDelegate;
}

@property(weak,nonatomic)id<addNewCellData>dataDelegate;
@property(strong,nonatomic)UITextField *codeTextfield;
@property(strong,nonatomic)UITextField *descTextfield;

@end
```

finally here is the AddNewCodeVC.m -

```
#import "AddNewCodeVC.h"

@interface AddNewCodeVC ()

@end

@implementation AddNewCodeVC

@synthesize dataDelegate;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.codeTextfield.delegate = self;
    self.descTextfield.delegate = self;

//Programmatically created both textfields, nothing special

}

//"saveNewCode" is action for another button i created
- (void)saveNewCode    {   
    sendDataToTableView:self.codeTextfield.text codeDesc:self.descTextfield.text];
    [self.dataDelegate sendDataToTableView:self.codeTextfield.text codeDesc:self.descTextfield.text];
    NSLog(@"CODE: %@", self.codeTextfield.text);
    NSLog(@"DESC: %@", self.descTextfield.text);
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

The code works but nsmutable array wont hold the passed values if i navigate away from the TableViewController. I think this is because my main view controller programmatically segues to the tableview controller and creates a new instance of it, so that might have some effect? I'll leave some code below just in case it is relevant.

MainviewController.m -

```
- (void) tableViewBtnPressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    TableViewController *tableVC = [[TableViewController alloc] init];
    //This for another delegate I created, not relevant
    tableVC.selectedDataDelegate = self;
    UINavigationController *navBar = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:tableVC];
    [self.navigationController presentViewController:navBar animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Hopefully this code is enough to illustrate the problem, i hope someone has an idea whats going on with the NSMutableArray, and why it isn't holding any new objects that are passed into it, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this a typo: `@implementation MCTableViewController` ? Should that be: `@implementation TableViewController` ? And why do you set the table view's `dataSource` and `delegate` in `viewDidLoad`? It's a `UITableViewController`. They are already set for you.

Comment: If you navigate away from the tableview controller and come back to it later then you are re-creating your arrays with the default data, so of course they won't have any values you added.  You need to persist your data in something like Core Data

Comment: What paul said is right. You can try presenting the AddNewCodeVC as modal. Or you can pass the whole array back and forth thru prepareForSegue and prepareForUnwindSegue. That way your data will remain,.

Comment: @GeneCode I think Core Data is a great idea, unfortunately i don't have much experience with it so i'll have to figure that out somehow. The prepareForUnwindSegue also seems like a good option, although my app doesn't use storyboards so I'm not sure if that can work? Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: Ah if you dont use storyboard, you can use NSUserdefaults to save your data and can be loaded back in between VCs.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use singleton if you dont want to write data often.

Comment: I was initially thinking of using NSUserDefaults but core data is important to learn so maybe i'll stick with that as a challenge. I'm confused on where to start with that though, would i save the whole NSMutableArray in core data? Or just add the core data objects to the array as is?

Comment: If you want to use core data, then you should add each object to each fields of coredata.